# how to fix fatal error during installation?

Tags: python, windows

hello to whom who concerned, how do I fix 0x80070643 - fatal error during installation? I am using windows 8.1 thanks everyone!!!

I tried watching on the internet and some, but it didn't work

Comment: What did you try to install?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to trace the error it said the file is corrupted, may be existing version of the app is outdated or changed. Uninstall the app using control panel and install new version.